# How do you multiply and divide in base1?

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

Base1 adds and subtracts but what about multiplying and dividing in base1?

Comment: It's pretty hard.  Ask the Romans.

Answer (score 2):

Well, multiplication is not hard:

E.g. let's do $3_{10} \cdot 5_{10}$, i.e $111_1 \cdot 11111_1$:

\begin{array}{r}
& 11111\\
& 111\\
\hline
& 11111\\
& 11111\\
& 11111\\
\hline
& 111111111111111\\
\end{array}

But division is what tore apart the Roman Empire.